# installing numpy for python 3.1.2 on Ubuntu 10.04

Tags: 10.04, python3

I have installed numpy for python 2.6.5. I want to use it for python 3.1.2 and I don't know how to install it. I'm new to ubuntu and I don't know how to install it from [tar](http://sourceforge.net/projects/numpy/files/) file. I am using Geany for programing in python3.  If I managed to installed it from there would it work in Geany?

Answer (score 0):

I have tried it on Ubuntu 11.10, but this should work. Download the numpy-1.6.2.tar.gz from [sourceforge](http://sourceforge.net/projects/numpy/files/NumPy/1.6.2/) than open a terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install python3-dev build-essential
tar xzf numpy-1.6.2.tar.gz
cd numpy-1.6.2
sudo python3 setup.py install
```

Than you need to wait for converting from python2 to python3 and to compile.