# Install Numpy for Python3.4.0 on Ubuntu 14.04.01 LTS

Tags: numpy

Python3.4.0 [comes by default](https://askubuntu.com/questions/449555/how-to-install-python-3-4-on-ubuntu) on Ubuntu 14.04.01 LTS. We can use it by typing on Terminal `python3.

I want to use Numpy for Python3.4.0. I run `import numpy
 but I had an`ImportError`.`So [I installed it by running](https://askubuntu.com/questions/200821/installing-numpy-for-python-3-1-2-on-ubuntu-10-04)sudo apt-get install python-numpy`. Then I typed on Terminal:`python3`. Then import numpy. I got this error:

```
>>> import numpy
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named 'numpy'
>>>
```

Nevertheless, Numpy is now working for Python-2.7:

```
begueradj@begueradj-Bill:~$ python
Python 2.7.6 (default, Mar 22 2014, 22:59:38) 
[GCC 4.8.2] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import numpy
>>>
```

How can I make Numpy work for Python 3.4.0 ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Open the terminal and type:

```
sudo apt-get install python3-numpy
```

python3-numpy is a fast array facility to the Python 3 language.