# import error:module named numpy

Tags: numpy

I am getting import error: module named `numpy`. Does this mean i have to install `numpy`? 
I have downloaded the new version extracted it into home. I am not sure what else to do. I am using Ubuntu 16.04. I have also tried:

```
sudo apt-get install python-pip
sudo apt-get install python3-numpy
```

But the error remains. Can anyone kindly guide me how to solve this

Comment: Please post the exact error message, and how you import numpy. Also: what is the python version you are using in the script, and how are you exactly running (calling) the script?

Comment: are you sure that your program uses python3? You might need to install `python-numpy` with `sudo apt-get install python-numpy` if your program uses python2 instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure that you are not trying to import numpy for Python 3.x into a Python 2.x program? In Ubunto 20.04 and earlier open the terminal and type:

```
sudo apt install python-numpy
```

If this works, it is the logical reverse of [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/588438/install-numpy-for-python3-4-0-on-ubuntu-14-04-01-lts/588449#588449).